# How can I compare items in two list that occur in the same position?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title says, I need to compare items in two list that occur in the same position.

```
la=['a0', 'b1', 'a2', 'b3', 'a4', 'b5'] 
lb=['b0', 'a1', 'b2', 'a3', 'b4', 'b5']
```

Like `'a0'` and `'b0'` for example

By comparing them, I want to delete from the list the one that is strictly greater that the other.If they are the same item, I want to delete them both from the list. The result of this function would be:

```
la=['a0','a2','a4']
lb=['a1','a3']
```

My problem is that I don't know how to compare each item.

I can use only the built-in functions from the standard Python library

Comment: Assuming this is (obviously) a homework question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nitpick: The problem, as described, does not match the sample input and output. When you compare `'b5'` with `'b5'`, neither one is *strictly greater* than the other, so neither one should be deleted. Therefore, both should still remain at the end of the function.

Comment: I tried using :

  if la[n] == lb[n]:
         del la[n]
        del lb[n]
  elif la[n] > lb[n] :
           del la[n]
  elif la[n] < lb[n] :
           del lb[n]

But i still need a value that change in the position of the item

Comment: You could have two indexes starting at zero, one for each list. they will increment in every iteration where you don't delete an element of their respective list. Use that index to do the comparison. OR you could simply create new lists and append the new items (this would be easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0
j = 0
while True:
    try:
        if la[i] > lb[j]:
            del la[i]
            j += 1
        elif la[i] < lb[j]:
            del lb[j]
            i += 1
        else:
            del la[i]
            del lb[j]
    except IndexError:
        break
```

This assumes both lists are the same length.  If you're removing element from one list and not the other you have to keep track of the indices separately.

Comment: This code will work even if the list are not the same length thanks to the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Since, what you are saying is equivalent to saying: let's take only the -strictly- smaller number from each list. You could do it like this:

```
new_la = []
new_lb = []

for i in range(len(la)):
    if la[i] < lb[i]:
        new_la.append(la[i])
    elif lb[i] < la[i]:
        new_lb.append(lb[i])

la = new_la
lb = new_lb
```

Notice that this code also creates new list instead of removing it in-place. This looks a bit more readable in my opinion.